# Datatables - Search on data-attribute only

Tags: javascript, search, datatables

I searched the web and this website for the proper info and there are many of them discussing the data-search but they are very specific and don't cover the basics I need. They didn't help me find a resolution to my problem.

I have a datatable with a custom search input

This input has an event attached to it to connect it to the datatable, and it works fine:

```
$('.search').keyup (function(){
    dataTable.search(this.value).draw();
});
```

On **each and every tbody td** of my table (even the empty ones), I added a "data-search" attribute with the value I want the search to be exclusively made on.

Here is a console screenshot that shows that fact:

[image]

But it doesn't work as the search is still made by default based on the td's html content.

I know for sure because here is an example: in one of my td's I have something like "**2 m<sup>2</sup>**" (the power is rendered with a 'sup' tag inside the cell) while in its data-search, I have a plain text "**2 m2**".

So if I type in the search box "**2 m**", I have a match but if I type "**2 m2**", there is no match anymore. So, it seems quite clear that the data-search attribute doesn't do much.

Here is my default datable configuration:

```
dataTable = $('.table_x').DataTable({
    'bInfo'     : false,
    'paging'    : false,
    'scrollX'   : false,
    'processing': false,
    'sDom'      : 'ltipr',
    'order'     : [[0,"asc"]],
    'colReorder': {realtime:true},
    'data'      : dataSet,    //ajax import
    'columns'   : dataColumns //ajax import
});
```

Should I need to add something to it in order to cancel the default search and target the data-search attribute instead?

I read this page of the Jquery datatables documentation but it doesn't seem to say there should be anything added, so I'm stuck:
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: here is how I dynamically feed my "dataColumns" variable here above:

```
// The columns are selected dynamically according to the user's preferences

function getTableData(){
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        url     : 'get_table_data.php',
        data    : '...',
        datatype: 'json',
        async   : false,
        cache   : false
    })
    .done (function(response){
        dataSet = JSON.parse(response);
        $.each(dataSet[0], function(key, value)
        {   
            var my_item = {};
                my_item.data = key ;
                my_item.title = key ;
                dataColumns.push(my_item);
        }); 
    })    
}
```

EDIT 2: This is **exactly** what I added according to the help I got but it still doesn't work:

```
dataTable = $('.table_x').DataTable({
    'bInfo'     : false,
    'paging'    : false,
    'scrollX'   : false,
    'processing': false,
    'sDom'      : 'ltipr',
    'order'     : [[0,"asc"]],
    'colReorder': {realtime:true},
    'data'      : dataSet,    //ajax import
    'columns'   : dataColumns //ajax import
});

$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row, index, rowData) => [...$(dataTable.row(index).node()).find('td')].map(td => $(td).attr('data-search')).some(tdAttr => tdAttr.includes($('#search').val().toLowerCase())))
```

With this: no error thrown but If I type "**2 m**", no match is met at all while both the data-search AND the td cell starts with "**2 m**".

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of custom search function [`$.fn.DataTable.ext.search`](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Plug-in-structure), like this:

```js
//source data (assuming your search attribute is part of a source data model)
const srcData = [
  {id: 1, name: 'apple', tag: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, name: 'banana', tag: 'fruit'},
  {id: 3, name: 'carrot', tag: 'vegie'},
  {id: 4, name: 'goosberry', tag: 'berry'},
  {id: 5, name: 'raspberry', tag: 'berry'}
];
//datatables initialization rendering each <td> with the attribute 'data-search'
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'id', data: 'id', createdCell: (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) => {
      $(td).attr('data-search', ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'][rowData.id-1]);
    }},
    {title: 'name', data: 'name', createdCell: (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) => {
      $(td).attr('data-search', rowData.tag);
    }}
  ]
})
//custom search across 'data-search' attributes of all cells
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row, index, rowData) => [...$(dataTable.row(index).node()).find('td')]
  .map(td => $(td).attr('data-search'))
  .some(tdAttr => 
    tdAttr.includes($('#search').val().toLowerCase())) || 
    $('#search').val() == '')
//redraw table upon search 'keyup'
$('#search').on('keyup', () => dataTable.draw());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<input id="search"></input>
<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't get it. This allows me to search 1 column (name). I have a dynamic table and there is no specific column to be searched. All I need is the global search on the whole table to be based on the data-search instead of the td's content. With that search plugin, I just don't see how I would proceed at all. As you can see in my question, the columns are imported dynamically by ajax (see EDIT) and the "dataColumns" could change anytime while ALL the columns should be impacted. I've seen your script in many places but as is, it doesn't seem to fit my requirements. does it?

Comment: Just to make myself clear: your script mention this: "//custom search across 'search-tag' attributes of 'name' column". My request is: "//custom search across 'search-tag' attributes of ANY column". I want the same than the default search, nothing specific, but on data-search attributes, not td's raw content.

Comment: Considering, you didn't share your data sample or minimal code context, I've made up my own example to demonstrate the concept, which is rather simple: you populate cell attributes with necessary values (no matter, using AJAX or not); you prepare external search function to search across attributes (not cell contents); you refresh data table upon search input to apply your custom search function.

Comment: Yeah well, I shared what needed to be shared. I said the data is dynamic so there is little I can share but a variable (which I did). I also said it was a search on ALL columns, not one. So there is nothing specific about it neither. So, please don't put in on me insinuating you eluded the question because of a lack of info as I never put it on you by saying you were not answering my question. I had the curtesy to say I didn't understand your answer instead. Moreover your last comment says it is simple but it doesn't say how to search through ALL columns while your code is specific to one.

Comment: In order to search across all columns (their 'search-data' attributes) you just need to slightly modify custom search function to something, like: `$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row, index, rowData) => [...$(dataTable.row(index).node()).find('td')].map(td => $(td).attr('data-search')).some(tdAttr => tdAttr.includes($('#search').val().toLowerCase()))`

Comment: ...of course, appending to above condition, matching empty search bar `|| $('#search').val() == ''`

Comment: Ok, thanks. What are these implying: "[...$()]" in your last bit of code? The previous bit didn't have the brackets and I don't see what the suspension points are supposed to replace. The whole thing is quite cryptic to me (not your fault at all, I'm just a noob). With my knowledge, I just took your script and added it in my code as is. I played with it too but the console only throws errors as I don't have the expertise to figure it out. Thanks for you patience and understanding

Comment: No worries. The part you're referring to is iterating over all `<td>` nodes, found within (each) particular row node,  `.map()` thing is expected to pull all 'data-search' attribute values out of those cells into an array, `.some()` checks whether among those values there's something  that includes searched keyword.

Comment: The only thing you should bear in mind, the code is using ES6 features extensively, some of them may be not supported by MS browsers, so you may need to translate those into legacy syntax if EDGE/IE is must.

Comment: Ok, let's be pragmatic :-) See edit 2 in my question to see what I exactly did according to your help. But It just doesn't work. What's wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: I have modified my code, so that it searches across entire table ('search-data' attribute values). You can now search by id's in their literal form ('one', 'two', etc). By the way: is there any particular reason you don't use datatable's [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option? So far, within code samples that your shared, I don't see anything that might cause it to go wrong. You may share distilled live example of your project on codepen or jsfiddle to play with, so that I can reproduce your issue. Otherwise, I can't see the way to guess what goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks. you did your best but I give up. I still don't know what are the suspension points for in your code, even though I asked, and it seems quite a thing to just search on a data attribute while their page on orthogonal search doesn't say a thing about using a plugin (the plugin seemed to be for very targeted search, not data attributes). It's most probably the language barrier but you and me just don't get each other. It feels like whatever I ask, you answer something else that I don't understand at all (it's 100% my faulty English and my lack of knowledge). Thank you very much.

Comment: Obviously, the code above does exactly what you're requesting for. Nevertheless, there's one last option you may try: if you populate 'data-search' attribute values of each cell from the same JSON (returned in response to AJAX-call), you use as a data source for your DataTable (just like I did for the second column in my example), you may try embedded search (`dataTable.search('2 m2').draw()`) as it will look through your data source even if you don't render those JSON properties as a visible table column.